# Exporting labels from QGIS shapefiles to AutoCAD with labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, export, cad

I have shapefiles in QGIS. I want to import labels also in AutoCAD drawing.
I tried to export DXF and open with autocad but labels not visible.

How to import labels in AutoCAD?

Comment: I know you're asking about AutoCAD but do you have Civil3D by any chance?

Comment: i don not have civil 3D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to import labels from QGIS into AutoCAD which can be found in the QGIS menu.  Project -> Import/Export -> Export Project to DXF.